# Cannot align multiline cell with single-line cell

Tags: tables, multicolumn, dcolumn

I am trying to align a row of cells where some cells are only 1 line and others are 2 lines. The MWE:

```
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro



\begin{table}[]
% let LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace amount
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
\centering

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{d{1.2}} }
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Dependent Variable ($+$ Additional Independent Variables)} \\
 \cmidrule{2-5}
 & \mc{Word 1 speed} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Word 1 speed \\ (+ intx)\end{tabular} & \mc{Word 2 speed} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Word 2 speed \\ (+ intx)\end{tabular} \\
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Dialogue act \\ F-score\end{tabular} & 2.53^{*} & 2.52^{*} & 4.45^{****} & 4.45^{****} \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

But it ends up looking like this:
[image]

I have also tried using `\makecell{}` for the multiline cells:

```
 & Word 1 speed & \makecell{Word 1 speed \\ (+ intx)} & Word 2 speed & \makecell{Word 2 speed \\ (+ intx)} \\
```

But my results do not look right at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a MWE showing the packages you used.

Comment: Thanks. Updated. Just dcolumn and makecell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you load the `makecell` package, you should make use of it instead of nesting tables, for example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn, makecell, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\makecell[#1]{#2}}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{table}[]
% let LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace amount
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
\centering

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{d{1.2}} }
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Dependent Variable ($+$ Additional Independent Variables)} \\
 \cmidrule{2-5}
 & \mc{c}{Word 1 speed} & \mc{c}{Word 1 speed \\ (+ intx)} & \mc{c}{Word 2 speed} & \mc{c}{Word 2 speed \\ (+ intx)} \\
\mc{l}{Dialogue act \\ F-score} & 2.53^{*} & 2.52^{*} & 4.45^{****} & 4.45^{****} \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The new `\mc` command essentially places a box made by `\makecell` inside the `\multicolumn` macro which is obviously needed here, because the column has a `d` specification and you need to overwrite this for proper alignment. I changed the original code for the `\mc` macro a bit so that it now takes two arguments, of which the first detones the alignment of the contents (`c` for centered, `l` for left-aligned). The alignment specification is done with the optional argument that the `\makecell` macro can take. So, if the first argument of the `\mc` macro is, for example, `l` you would have a left-aligned `\makecell` inside a left-aligned `\multicolumn` macro, because the argument is fed to both. I only considered horizontal alignment here. For vertical alignment, see Zarko's nice answer.

[image]

Comment: This does not look correct. The 4th column should be “Word 2 speed”. But in this screenshot it is in the same column as “Word 1 speed”

Comment: Well, since you did not provide an image how it should look like exactly, I had to understand your code first. It should be right now, I guess?

Comment: Yup, thank you! Sorry about that!

Comment: Would you explaining the structure of your `\mc` function?

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

[image]

- It is not clear, how text should be aligned. I consider, that is desired to be vertical centered. If this is not a case, than you can align at:

  - top of multi lines text by `\makecell[t]{...}`, or at
  - bottom of multi lines text by `\makecell[b]{...}`.
- All column headers had to be in `multicolumn` cells. For their shortness I suggest to use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
% let LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace amount
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\centering

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{d{1.2}} }
    &   \mcc[4]{Dependent Variable ($+$ Additional Independent Variables)} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
        & \mcc{Word 1 speed}
            &   \mcc{\makecell{Word 1 speed \\ (+ intx) }}
                &   \mcc{Word 2 speed}
                    &   \mcc{\makecell{Word 2 speed \\ (+ intx) }}      \\
    \midrule
\makecell{Dialogue act \\ F-score} 
    & 2.53^{*} & 2.52^{*} & 4.45^{****} & 4.45^{****}   \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Addendum:

- align at top of multi lines column headers:

```
...
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{d{1.2}} }
    &   \mcc[4]{Dependent Variable ($+$ Additional Independent Variables)} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
        & \mcc{Word 1 speed}
            &   \mcc{\makecell[t]{Word 1 speed \\ (+ intx) }}
                &   \mcc{Word 2 speed}
                    &   \mcc{\makecell[t]{Word 2 speed \\ (+ intx) }}      \\
    \midrule
...
```

[image]

- align at bottom of multilines colummn headers

```
...
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{d{1.2}} }
    &   \mcc[4]{Dependent Variable ($+$ Additional Independent Variables)} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
        & \mcc{Word 1 speed}
            &   \mcc{\makecell[b]{Word 1 speed \\ (+ intx) }}
                &   \mcc{Word 2 speed}
                    &   \mcc{\makecell[b]{Word 2 speed \\ (+ intx) }}      \\
    \midrule
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I did not take into account vertical alignment in my answer, but you did.

Comment: On the first line of the table this throws the error `Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (1.2): 'c' used.`

Comment: @Adam_G, you are right. Correct definition od `d` column is `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}`. It was considered in my compilation for producing showed images. Corected now.